# Mapping one collection of objects into another collection of objects

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have a collection of objects, let's say models, that all implement the same interface. They are all stored in a literal collection. I would like to map them now to different objects and the mapping should happen solely based on the type of the model from the collection.

To explain using a noob solution as an example, I could loop over the collection, check the type of the object using `instanceof`, and based on that select the class of the object I want to map it to and initiate the mapping. So that is the wrong solution, what is the right solution?

Comment: The interface that they implement should include a method that performs the mapping. Call that method in the loop.

Comment: Any time you find yourself "checking the type" of something in OOP, there's a good chance you're doing something wrong. It should usually by done by calling a method that will be dispatched to the appropriate class automatically.

Comment: but then I have doubts if this is not to much responsibility for a model/dto that is just representing some structure to have such functionality?

Comment: It's the right modularity. Otherwise you'll need a bunch of `instanceof` checks that will have to be updated any time you add a new model class. That's an OOP anti-pattern.